# Problem in Loading NK.bin

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce

I have one weired problem with our NK.bin. It is loading in one device and not in other device , however both device is same. what can be the problem ..??
while loading it is not giving response like some flickering and all...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same NK.BIN file then there are only a few options:

1. Your bootloader of configuration files (if the device uses them) between the two devices are different
2. The hardware on the non-working device is actually different (a different revision maybe).
3. The board (or some connection to it) is bad.  It sounds like you're an OEM.  Check your cables, then if it still fails, send the board back for manufacturing tests - it's likely has a part failure.